# Employer wants me to get an EIN for contract work. Is this okay, and if so, what kind should I choose?

Tags: united-states, business

I recently got offered a job opportunity to do contract work with an IT company. But along with all the usual paperwork, it's mandatory that obtain and submit an EIN.

But I'm not sure which type I should get, or if even OK to do.

Comment: See https://www.irs.gov/businesses/small-businesses-self-employed/employer-id-numbers. The EIN is just a tax identification number; for individuals that is typically just your SSN or ITIN if you aren't eligible for a SSN. It's not clear that you need one. (Of course, the company may have reasons for not wanting to contract with individuals.)